# How to select a color in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program written in Python, that makes a window where you can draw, using Tkinter. Every time you left-click your mouse, you make a point in your canvas. When you double-click, a polygon is made, filled with the color you chose. I found a way to change the colors from the boxes, when you right-click a box, but the problem is that the selected color is not saved and i cannot make it replace the previous one. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import colorchooser

class Point():
    
    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        canvas.create_oval(x-2, y-2, x+2, y+2, fill='white') 

class Poly():
    
    def __init__(self, canvas, board, p_list=[] ):
        self.p_list = p_list
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.board = board

    def draw_poly(self):
        points = []
        for p in self.p_list:
            points.extend([p.x, p.y])
        points.extend(points[:2])
        self.canvas.create_polygon(points, fill=self.board.current_color, outline=self.board.current_color)

    def add_point(self, p):
        self.p_list.append(p)
        if len(self.p_list)>1:
            p1 = self.p_list[-1]
            p2 = self.p_list[-2]
            self.canvas.create_line(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, fill="white", width=2)

class Palette():
    
    def __init__(self, frame, board, colors):
        self.colors = colors
        self.board = board
        self.allColors = []
        for color in self.colors:
            f = tk.Frame(frame, bg='lightgrey', bd=3)
            f.pack(expand=1, fill='both', side='left')
            if self.board.current_color == color: f.config(bg='red')
            self.allColors.append(f)
            l = tk.Label(f, bg=color)
            l.pack(expand=1, fill='both', padx=2, pady=2)
            l.bind("<1>", self.set_color)

            l.bind("<Button-3>", self.do_popup)

    def do_popup(self, event):
        clsheet = tk.colorchooser.askcolor()
        self.current_color = clsheet[1]
        
    def set_color(self, e):
        self.board.current_color = e.widget['bg']
        self.selected_color(e.widget.master)
    
    def selected_color(self, colorFrame):
        for f in self.allColors: f.config(bg = 'lightgrey')
        colorFrame.config(bg="red")

class Board():
    
    
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.colors = ['#B4FE98', '#77E4D4', '#F4EEA9',  '#F0BB62', '#FF5F7E', "#9A0680"]
        self.root = root
        self.current_color = self.colors[0]
        self.f1 = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.f1.pack(expand=1, fill='both', padx=5)
        self.f2 = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.f2.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.f2, bg="#000D6B", height=550)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=1, fill='both', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.pallette = Palette(self.f1, self, self.colors )
        self.canvas.bind("<1>", self.draw_point)
        self.canvas.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.draw_poly)
        
        self.poly = None

    def draw_point(self, evnt):
        if self.poly: self.poly.add_point(Point(self.canvas, evnt.x, evnt.y))
        else: self.poly = Poly(self.canvas, self, [Point(self.canvas, evnt.x, evnt.y)])

    def draw_poly(self, evnt):
        if self.poly and len(self.poly.p_list) > 2:
            self.poly.add_point(Point(self.canvas, evnt.x, evnt.y))
            self.poly.draw_poly()
            self.poly = None
        else: self.draw_point(evnt)

#main program
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('my program')
root.geometry("600x700")
root.resizable(0,0)
Board(root)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where are you facing trouble

Comment: you mean that right after creating a filled polygon, you want to be able to select color from the menu and it will replace the fill color?

Comment: Yes, my problem is that i am able to select color from the menu, but the color does not replace the fill color

Comment: AFAI can see, `colorchooser` is not used

Comment: Yes it is, in the do_popup() function

Comment: yes, but it doesn't really do anything or did you mean to use `self.board.current_color` there? to configure the fill color you need to get either the tag of that polygon or id (likely the id), then you need to use `itemconfigure` and change the fill, the issues is that your structure is a bit of a mess, you need to save the id to some global variable when you create the poly and when you change colors, check if there is an id to be configured and configure its color

Comment: How do you "save" *anything else* about your program's data while it is running?  By assigning a variable, right? And then checking that value when you need it? It seems like you are already attempting to do this, through `self.board.current_color`. If you are looking for debugging help, then you should *ask the question in a way that reflects that*.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the part where right-clicking a color was not working i changed two things in your script:

1. You stored your frame widgets and their sub-widget labels in `Palette.allColors`. I handed over the index of the selected color to the do_popup event by using `partial`. Then you can simply iterate over all widgets in `Palette.allColors` and if the index from the event matches the index in the list, you access the children and further the `!label` key of those and change the background color to the selected color.
2. I matched `Board.current_color` and `Palette.current_color`

Most changes were made in `Palette.do_popup()`. Might not be the most elegant solution but it looks like its working like you intend. Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import colorchooser
from functools import partial


class Point():

    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        canvas.create_oval(x - 2, y - 2, x + 2, y + 2, fill='white')


class Poly():

    def __init__(self, canvas, board, p_list=[]):
        self.p_list = p_list
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.board = board

    def draw_poly(self):
        points = []
        for p in self.p_list:
            points.extend([p.x, p.y])
        points.extend(points[:2])
        self.canvas.create_polygon(points, fill=self.board.current_color, outline=self.board.current_color)

    def add_point(self, p):
        self.p_list.append(p)
        if len(self.p_list) > 1:
            p1 = self.p_list[-1]
            p2 = self.p_list[-2]
            self.canvas.create_line(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, fill="white", width=2)


class Palette():

    def __init__(self, frame, board, colors):
        self.colors = colors
        self.board = board
        self.allColors = []
        for idx, color in enumerate(self.colors):
            f = tk.Frame(frame, bg='lightgrey', bd=3)
            f.pack(expand=1, fill='both', side='left')
            if self.board.current_color == color: f.config(bg='red')
            self.allColors.append(f)
            l = tk.Label(f, bg=color)
            l.pack(expand=1, fill='both', padx=2, pady=2)
            l.bind("<1>", self.set_color)

            l.bind("<Button-3>", partial(self.do_popup, idx))

    def do_popup(self, idx, event):
        clsheet = tk.colorchooser.askcolor()
        self.current_color = clsheet[1].upper()
        print(f"You chose: {self.current_color}")
        self.board.current_color = self.current_color  # required?
        self.selected_color(event.widget.master)
        for frm_idx, frm in enumerate(self.allColors):
            if frm_idx == idx:
                frm.children["!label"].config(bg=self.current_color)

    def set_color(self, e):
        self.board.current_color = e.widget['bg']
        self.selected_color(e.widget.master)

    def selected_color(self, colorFrame):
        for f in self.allColors: f.config(bg='lightgrey')
        colorFrame.config(bg="red")


class Board():

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.colors = ['#B4FE98', '#77E4D4', '#F4EEA9', '#F0BB62', '#FF5F7E', "#9A0680"]
        self.root = root
        self.current_color = self.colors[0]
        self.f1 = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.f1.pack(expand=1, fill='both', padx=5)
        self.f2 = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.f2.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.f2, bg="#000D6B", height=550)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=1, fill='both', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.pallette = Palette(self.f1, self, self.colors)
        self.canvas.bind("<1>", self.draw_point)
        self.canvas.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.draw_poly)

        self.poly = None

    def draw_point(self, evnt):
        if self.poly:
            self.poly.add_point(Point(self.canvas, evnt.x, evnt.y))
        else:
            self.poly = Poly(self.canvas, self, [Point(self.canvas, evnt.x, evnt.y)])

    def draw_poly(self, evnt):
        if self.poly and len(self.poly.p_list) > 2:
            self.poly.add_point(Point(self.canvas, evnt.x, evnt.y))
            self.poly.draw_poly()
            self.poly = None
        else:
            self.draw_point(evnt)


# main program
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('my program')
root.geometry("600x700")
root.resizable(0, 0)
Board(root)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the OP's problem. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70452149/how-to-select-a-color-in-tkinter#comment124540292_70452149): the OP wants everything drawn on the canvas to be changed to the selected color when it's selected. This code keeps the color of the shapes even when you select a different color.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Hm - after re-reading it - you might be right. Lets see what OP has to say

Comment: Oh wait... I noticed you _did_ fix the right-click-color-change-not-working problem (sorry, I didn't test for that). So it's part of what the OP needed, I guess. If you edit your answer, I can un-downvote it. The question was unclear; I only figured out what they really wanted by reading the clarification comments below the question :-/.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin No problem - thanks for pointing it out, i hope my answer is clearer now after editing it. :)

Comment: In fact, you get an upvote, because you _did_ answer the OP's _question_, which was _"How to select a color in Tkinter?"_. And thanks for making the answer more clear about what it is fixing!